# Unable to send IM to user on different domain using Java SMACK

Tags: jakarta-ee, smack, jira-plugin

The following snippet is picked out of a JIRA plugin I'm writing to (hopefully) notify people (co-workers) via an IM (gchat in my case) when they've been @mentioned on a JIRA ticket.

```
   import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
   import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
   import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
   import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
   import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
   import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
   import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

   ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(<server>, <port>, <domain>);
   XMPPConnection connection = New XMPPConnection(config);

   connection.connect();
   connection.login(someone@domain_a.com, <password>);

   ChatManager chatManager = connection.getChatManager();

   Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(someone@domain_b, new MessageListener() {
      public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {
          System.out.println("Received message "+ msg);
      }
   });

   chat.sendMessage(<msg>);
```

My issue is that I'm able to send the IM notifications to users that share the domain of the user who was authenticated at the line:

```
connection.login(someone@domain_a.com, <password>);
```

But not others - eg:
I can send from somone@**domain_a.com** to someon_else@**domain_a.com** but NOT able to send it to someone_else@**domain_b.com**...

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and answer my noob mistake:

The issue was that the user that's authenticated didn't have the user they were attempting to send the message to (from the different domain) on their chat list...

Once they were "friends" it worked no problem #facepalm